# How would i get my query to compare prices?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Afternoon,

I would like to return a bool if the prices match. I am returning 3 different prices, however i need to compare if lowprice and amzprice are the same. If they are i need to also return...

```
pricematched = true
```

Below is my current query.

```
 var query = from a in dc.aProducts
             join t in dc.tProducts on a.sku equals t.sku
             join lp in dc.LowestPrices on a.asin equals lp.productAsin
             orderby t.title
             select new GetLowestPrices
             {
                 productAsin = lp.productAsin,
                 sku = t.sku,
                 title = t.title,
                 oprice = Convert.ToString(t.tPrice),
                 lowprice = Convert.ToString(lp.price),
                 amzprice = Convert.ToString(lp.tAmzPrice),
                 lastupdated = Convert.ToDateTime(lp.priceDate)
            };
            return query.ToList();
```

all help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can limit using a where statement, `where lp.price = lp.tAmzPrice`.  Is there a reason this must be done with linq?

Comment: I am using Linq in my web service, and throughout the site. I need to display all results not just limit them thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add the boolean to your existing object, it just factors into the query like below:

```
 var query = from a in dc.aProducts
         join t in dc.tProducts on a.sku equals t.sku
         join lp in dc.LowestPrices on a.asin equals lp.productAsin
         orderby t.title
         select new GetLowestPrices
         {
             productAsin = lp.productAsin,
             sku = t.sku,
             title = t.title,
             oprice = Convert.ToString(t.tPrice),
             lowprice = Convert.ToString(lp.price),
             amzprice = Convert.ToString(lp.tAmzPrice),
             lastupdated = Convert.ToDateTime(lp.priceDate),
             pricematched = lp.tAmzPrice >= lp.price    // This should do it
        };
        return query.ToList();
```

Otherwise you'll have to do it outside the query with a secondary query:

```
var matchedItems = query.Where(x => x.amzprice >= x.lowprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select new GetLowestPrices
         {
             productAsin = lp.productAsin,
             sku = t.sku,
             title = t.title,
             oprice = Convert.ToString(t.tPrice),
             lowprice = Convert.ToString(lp.price),
             amzprice = Convert.ToString(lp.tAmzPrice),
             lastupdated = Convert.ToDateTime(lp.priceDate),
             pricematched = lp.price == lp.tAmzPrice
        };
```

Incidentally, why strings for the prices? Also:

```
return query.ToList();
```

If you can get away with `return query` instead of making a list, then do.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to do this using jquery instead.